# Magento 2.0 Checkbox required validation not triggering

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, validation, checkbox

the checkbox required field validation in my code doesn't seem to get triggered on submit although the other input fields are validated.  Can any of you check out what the hell's wrong in my code?

```
<div class="field">
    <label class="label" for="custom_second">
        <span><?php  echo __('Item Delivery Options') ?></span>
    </label>
    <div class="control">
        <?php foreach($deliveryOptionList as $key => $deliveryOptionItem): ?>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input class="radio validate-one-required-by-name" type="checkbox" name="rahahaha_data[delivery_options][]" value="<?php echo $key; ?>"> <?php echo $deliveryOptionItem; ?>
            </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div> 
</div>
```

This is how the output looks like:

```
<div class="field">
<label class="label" for="custom_second">
    <span>Item Delivery Options</span>
</label>
<div class="control">
    <label class="radio-inline">
    <input class="radio validate-one-required-by-name" type="checkbox" name="rahahaha_data[delivery_options][]" value="1"> Rahahaha - online payment</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <label class="radio-inline">
    <input class="radio validate-one-required-by-name" type="checkbox" name="rahahaha_data[delivery_options][]" value="2"> Rahahaha - cash on delivery</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <label class="radio-inline">
    <input class="radio validate-one-required-by-name" type="checkbox" name="rahahaha_data[delivery_options][]" value="4"> Sellers delivery</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <label class="radio-inline">
    <input class="radio validate-one-required-by-name" type="checkbox" name="rahahaha_data[delivery_options][]" value="5"> Buyers pick-up</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>
```

Thanks guys

Comment: This are the other things I have tested:
added the class "checkbox required", 
using " data-validate", 
changing the name to regular array : delivery_options[]

Comment: apparently add the class "checkbox required" and clearing the cache seem to have triggered the validation.  but... the error message is not showing up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do below code, use `class name as checkbox required` to validate checkbox,

```
<div class="field">
    <label class="label" for="custom_second">
        <span><?php  echo __('Item Delivery Options') ?></span>
    </label>
    <div class="control">
        <?php foreach($deliveryOptionList as $key => $deliveryOptionItem): ?>
           <input class="checkbox required" type="checkbox" name="rahahaha_data[delivery_options][]" value="<?php echo $key; ?>">
            <label class="label radio-inline">
                 <?php echo $deliveryOptionItem; ?>
            </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Rakesh thanks for the feedback, but it is still not working.  I've updated my post to include the things I have tested that did not work.

Comment: i have updated my answer plz keep above code.

Comment: ok i tried the change the class again and deleted the cache folder from the var.  i can now see a mage-error class being added to the first checkbox.  there is no error message though.

Comment: Have you checked inside inspect element, whether message is display or not?

Comment: yeah i did.  there was no message.  but i am sure the validation now triggered.  this is the code of the first checkbox whenever i do not select any of the checkboxes:<label for="delivery_options_1">
 <input id="delivery_options_1" data-validate="{'validate-one-required-by-name':true}" class="checkbox required mage-error" type="checkbox" name="rahahaha_data[delivery_options][]" value="1" aria-invalid="true"> Rahahaha - online payment                
</label>

Comment: i marked this as answer but you still have idea why the error message is not showing?

Comment: i have same issue but i have display message after first checkbox. May be you could add id for input.

Comment: ok i found the error.  we need to move the input checkbox outside the label.  it should not be inside the label.  the message is showing now.

Comment: i have done same code above.