# Magento 2 : Terms and Condition validation not working on checkout page

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, validation, terms-and-conditions

I moved terms and condition functionality in checkout order summary block.

But, There are no any validation working before click on place order button.

I also added agreement validation code in my custom module `checkout_index_index.xml`

> checkout_index_index.xml :

```
<item name="agreements" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_CheckoutAgreements/js/view/checkout-agreements</item>
    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">100</item>
    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">before-place-order</item>
    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">checkoutAgreements</item>
    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
</item>
<item name="agreements-validator" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_CheckoutAgreements/js/view/agreement-validation</item>
</item>
```

[image]

How to do it ?

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: How'd you manage to place the order and checkout button in the sidebar? I've followed some Stack topics about that, but unfortunately no luck (my question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/220895/moving-place-order-button-terms-and-conditions-checkbox-after-payment-methods)

Comment: Yes. My code also same as like your code. But, not getting any solution. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: My code isn't even working unfortunately (maybe you have any ideas why is doesn't?) I did not come to the point where I could look into the validation function. Maybe this is something of use? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110643/magento-2-0-checkbox-required-validation-not-triggering

Comment: I've managed to replace the place order button and t&c checkbox. Now also searching for a solution to this

Comment: I've found out (I think) why this happens, but not how to fix it: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/222416/validation-of-the-terms-and-conditions-custom-module

Comment: Did you already find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check my following answer regarding the same issue you were facing:

[Validation of the terms and conditions (custom module)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/222416/validation-of-the-terms-and-conditions-custom-module/227699#227699)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: hi @Bram, here you are trying with custom module, for me default is not working, can you please update me the fix